# 301 redirect is adding content to the end of each new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

this is a very useful site and I have read as many similar questions as I can on this issue but simply can't get my 301 redirects to work. I think it is because I don't understand the complicated redirect code in the answers I have read so I don't know how to change the code in the answers to meet my specific needs. So I do hope someone can help me please.

I had an old shop with urls that look like this:

categories looked like this: /store/cid-45-1/dog_collar_lead.html
products looked like this: /store/pid-218/dog_tshirt_princess.html

I now have a new shop from a different cart software provider (hosted this time so I have had to use a sub-domain, in case that info is important at all) and I want to redirect all my old urls from my old shop to my new shop. I spent hours setting the 301 redirect list up the way I have always done it but it is not working :-(

So one of my lines, that I have added to my htaccess file looks like this:

Redirect 301 /store/cid-72-1/dog_collars_leads_hotdogs.html http://shop.mydomain.co.uk/leather-dog-collars-leads.html

but it redirects to this, which is not right:

http://shop.mydomain.co.uk/leather-dog-collars-leads.html?pg1-cid72.html

This pg1-cid72.html and similar is getting lumped onto the end of all my new urls. I can't work out how to stop that happening. After hours trying all the different replies I have found on here to other questions I am still unable to get it to work so in desperation I put a ? on the end of each url and it has stopped the spurious pg1-cid72.html type stuff appearing but has given me a ? at the end of each url which I feel is better but still not correct.  I am so worried Google will not like this and will penalise my site or something. I am even thinking if I can't get this to work maybe I should scrap all my 301 redirect attempts and just let 404s be returned?

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you so much,

Jenny

Thank you for the replies so far.  My htaccess currently looks like this, after adding the suggested code from a reply below:

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.co.uk [nc] rewriterule ^(.*)$     http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [r=301,nc]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html

Redirect 301 /hotcars http://www.mydomain.co.uk/didyouknow_parked_cars.htm
Redirect 301 /charities_k9knitters.htm http://www.mydomain.co.uk    /charities_woollies_waggers.htm

RewriteRule ^/store/cid-94-1/doza_cushion_dog_bed\.html$ http://shop.mydomain.co.uk/dog-cushions.html [R=301]
```

So implementing the suggested fix, now I get re-directed to store/ at the old store and not re-directed to the new shop.

Sorry, I am trying to post a better reply but keep getting told I can't post more than 2 links, which is hampering my reply. I hope it is clear and hope you can help. Thank you.

When I visit

```
http://www.dfordog.co.uk/store/cid-92-1/wooden_raised_dog_feeders.html
```

I hope to end up at

```
http://shop.dfordog.co.uk/raised-dog-bowls.html
```

But I end up at

```
http://shop.dfordog.co.uk/raised-dog-bowls.html?pg1-cid92.html
```

Same for all of them.  So basically the Avactis code part of the url cid-92-1 which in it's non-user friendly format was pg1-cid92.html is being added to the end of all my new shop urls when redirected from the old shop.

Standard Avactis urls had this kind of thing/code in them pg1-cid92.html etc... and I chose to have a more user-friendly format shown to the customers cid-92-1 by seleceting the user-friendly option when I set the cart up last year.  I am pretty sure it is something to do with that.

I found this topic on the Avactis forum

```
http://www.avactis.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=3114
```

and think it somehow could help but his situation was slightly different to mine in that his Avactis urls were not converted to the user-friendly urls mine uses... so I am not sure how to apply this advice to my situation.

Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) instead, without the [[QSA]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag (which by default, is not in effect - so just don't add it):

```
RewriteRule ^/store/cid-72-1/dog_collars_leads_hotdogs\.html$ http://shop.mydomain.co.uk/leather-dog-collars-leads.html [R=301]
```

Either the `?pg1-cid72.html` is part of the original request to the original page, or you have some other rules in effect somewhere that are adding this on - in which case we'd need to see your complete Apache configuration and .htaccess file to offer any additional assistance.

Neither this nor any of your other rules are taking effect, however, because of the first `RewriteRule` at the beginning of your `.htaccess`, which is applying to and redirecting everything from the old domain:

```
rewriterule ^(.*)$
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  Unfortunatley it is not working. The old ulr now gets redirected to /store

Comment: The entire contents of my htaccess is as follows now: RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.co.uk [nc] rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [r=301,nc]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html

Redirect 301 /hotcars http://www.mydomain.co.uk/didyouknow_parked_cars.htm
Redirect 301 /charities_k9knitters.htm http://www.mydomain.co.uk/charities_woollies_waggers.htm

RewriteRule ^/store/cid-94-1/doza_cushion_dog_bed\.html$ http://shop.mydomain.co.uk/dog-cushions.html [R=301]

Comment: @Jenny - Need additional details...  What is the exact URL you're seeing it be redirected to, vs. what exactly do you expect?

Comment: cid-number and pid-number was the system my old cart used for category and product pages.

Comment: I have added some info to my original post :-) Please let me know if you need any other info. My old cart was Avactis. I think all the Avactis pages used to follow this kind of format pg1-cid72.html but my cart with Avactis had more user friendly pages so it was converted to this /store/cid-72-1/dog_collars_leads_hotdogs.html. So it looks like when re-directing it is adding the old pg1-cid72.html onto each url.

Comment: I sort of get it and also found this helpful to a point http://www.avactis.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=3114 but what was suggested in the reply there is not working for me because my case is slightly different in that my old store was using the user friendly urls not the same url format as this chap who got help.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, what we are writing is taking effect but just not the right effect :-) That top piece of code is just to redirect all non-www to www isn't it? Thank you for your help... but I am not understanding.  I think here gives us maybe the biggest clue to solving this but I can't make head nor tail of how it applies to me http://www.avactis.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=3114

Comment: @Jenny - unfortunately, I'm not getting the answers that I need to properly answer this question.  If you had more rep, I'd invite you to chat.  Given that, can you please re-review the comments here and update with exactly what you're seeing (full URLs) vs. what you're expecting?  Put them in code blocks if you need to bypass the SO filter you were having problems with.  Also, simplify your .htaccess and get each part working one at a time, then work on trying to combine them together.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my original post to add things in a clearer way. I hope that makes more sense and am so sorry if I was not clear the first time.

Comment: QSA has no effect in this case. You simply need to add a `?` to the url you want to redirect to. This, together with QSA not being enabled makes apache remove the querystring. Secondly, if your the rewriterule is located in the htaccess it never starts with a `/`.  So it must be `RewriteRule ^store/cid-72-1/dog_collars_leads_hotdogs\.html$ http://shop.mydomain.co.uk/leather-dog-collars-leads.html? [R=301]`

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.  I will try that :-) Can you tell me please what QSA is?  Or don't I have to worry about that?

Comment: @Jenny - click on the linked QSA at the top of this answer.